# Why Is This Where Predicate Not Test-Covered?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, unit-testing, code-coverage

**tl;dr**... Code coverage reports 1 non-covered block with:

```
.Where(x => x.Field1.Contains(someValue) ||
            x.Field2.Contains(someValue))
```

Even though all of that code executes.

---

One of my methods has a `.Where()` predicate applied to an enumeration.  Simplified, the method does this:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeType> Filter(IEnumerable<SomeType> source, string filter)
{
    return source.Where(x => x.SomeField.Contains(filter) ||
                             x.AnotherField.Contains(filter) ||
                             x.AThirdField.Contains(filter));
}
```

(There are actually 8 comparisons total in the original code.)  My unit test passes a source with a handful of elements and a string that wouldn't be found in any of them, to validate that none are returned.  The test passes, but the code coverage highlights the three lines in the predicate and says that there's one not-covered block.

What's not covered?  Wouldn't all of this code execute in the test of it's indeed not finding any results?  In the "hierarchy" column in Visual Studio's code coverage results, it lists this method as containing that one block:

```
<Filter>b__6(class SomeType)
```

At first I thought that maybe the compiled code is optimized should there be a field without a value, so that it never bothers with `.Contains()` on such a field.  But I've confirmed that at least one element in `source` has all fields set with values, so I would think that all of the checks would be made.

What am I missing?

---

**Edit:** The non-contrived code, verbatim, is:

```
results = results.Where(o =>
    o.RemoteOccurrence.PatientName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()) ||
    o.RemoteOccurrence.HealthID.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()) ||
    o.RemoteOccurrence.OccurrenceType.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()) ||
    o.RemoteOccurrence.PrimaryDiagnosis.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()) ||
    o.RemoteOccurrence.Description.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()) ||
    o.RemoteOccurrence.PrimaryClinician.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()) ||
    o.ReviewStatus.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()));
```

The test data includes:

```
var entry = new ReviewOccurrence
{
    ReviewStatus = ReviewOccurrence.Status.New,
    RemoteOccurrence = new RemoteOccurrence
    {
        PatientName = "Jane Doe",
        HealthID = "12345",
        OccurrenceType = "ER to Admit Patient",
        PrimaryDiagnosis = "COPD",
        Description = "This is a test",
        PrimaryClinician = "Nurse Suzy"
    }
    // other unrelated fields
};
```

And the value of `filter` is "filter" which isn't in any of those fields.

---

**Update:**

I've taken the contrived example and created a runnable test from it, starting with only a single field to filter:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyWrapper
{
    private List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>()
    {
        new MyObject { Name = "David" }
    };

    public IEnumerable<MyObject> Filter(string filter)
    {
        return objects.Where(o => o.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()));
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var results = new MyWrapper().Filter("foo");
    Assert.AreEqual(0, results.Count());
}
```

Test passes, coverage is 100%.  So I add another field to the object (call it `Description`) and add to the clause:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> Filter(string filter)
{
    return objects.Where(o => o.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()) ||
                              o.Description.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()));
}
```

Test still passes, but now there's that 1 missing block of code coverage again.  So it seems to be related to the chaining of clauses with the `||` operator between them.  (Or at least the compiled result thereof.)

Continuing to tinker, I change it to this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> Filter(string filter)
{
    return objects.Where(o => o.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant()))
                  .Union(objects.Where(o => o.Description.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant())));
}
```

Test passes, back to 100% code coverage.  Definitely the `||` clauses, but it's still not clear to me why.

Comment: My strong suspicion is that your sample data does in fact match, and you're not aware of it, thus short-circuiting the `or` operation. Double check your data and your input.

Comment: @DavidHaney: Double- and triple-checked.  I thought so too, but any string I use has the same result.  I can confidently assure you that the string "zakjhsdf" doesn't exist in the test data.

Comment: @David Does the relevant unit test(s) throw an exception if there are any items in the resulting sequence, to verify this?

Comment: @Servy: The test asserts that the resulting sequence has a count of 0, which passes.  Stepping through in a debugger visually confirms this as well.

Comment: @David try forcing the enumeration as `.ToList()` just for kicks.

Comment: @DavidHaney Counting the sequence would do that.

Comment: @Servy I'm aware, but I wonder if the count in the test context is different than the count in the code context in which coverage is indicated.

Comment: @DavidHaney: Same result.  That would have potentially made sense too, if the deferred execution was optimized in some way unfamiliar to me in this scenario.  But it doesn't look like that's the culprit.

Comment: @David Are you covering the case where this code throws an exception?  Say, for example, by having one of those fields be `null`?

Comment: @David I would say that logically it HAS to be that your code is wrong or input matches. Show us the actual predicate? Alternatively, test your contrived example above as a sanity check. :)

Comment: @Servy: I am.  I'm also covering the scenario where at least one record is found.  All pass, it's just the coverage that's eluding me by one block somewhere.

Comment: @DavidHaney: I've updated the question with less-contrived verbatim code/data.  If it is an issue with my logic, that would be a relief.  All I'd have to do is find it and all will be well.

Comment: Have you turned on code coverage highlighting on the IDE?

Comment: @DavidHaney: Yup, and the highlighted portion specifically covers the start of the very first `o.Remote...` to the end of the last `...Invariant())`.  Basically everything in the anonymous function.  Specifically it's the "light red" highlight, indicating partial coverage.

Comment: I believe you need a test case to match each individual part of the `or` operation in order to achieve full coverage.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and update are you using?

Comment: @OmegaMan: Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the or condition is short circuiting because one of the earlier conditions evaluates to true and you aren't testing the remaining condition, thus not getting 100% code coverage. For example, you wouldn't get full coverage on the following:

```
var x = true;
var y = false;

var result = x || y;
```

In this case, when checking for result, x is evaluated, but y isn't because x already meets the or condition. If you really need 100% coverage, you need to test all possible permutations of or conditions (often a tedious exercise).

Comment: I would have thought that originally as well, but the data and the results of the test demonstrate otherwise.  The string "filter" is most definitely *not* found in that test record.  (Unless `.Contains()` is doing something different than I expect?)

Comment: This was proposed in comments long before this answer was posted, and it was shown to not be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the contrived code could provide the answer you seek.

Create a separate solution which clone's the predicate scenario, but only in a `strawman` or *very* base way. Verify the code coverage is full and then begin to add conditions one by one, `woodman`, `tinman`, etc until either you have duplicated the situation or the clone is fully test covered and functional.

The difference if any found could lead you to why the originating code is not fully covered.

---

### Update

What is code coverage? Something that Visual Studio informs us graphically on...hence we rely on it. But what if there is a bug in the code Visual Studio uses to determine the area of code coverage?

---

### Negative Tests and Postive Tests Achieve 100%

I decided to write a connect bug with the scenario presented and began testing but with different situations. I changed the Filter code to `or` on these two *competing* conditions but where both would be hit:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> Filter(string filter)
{
    return objects.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(filter) ||
                            o.Name.Contains(filter) == false);
}
```

Then the first test where foo was not in any of the items so the second or condition would be hit

```
var results = new MyWrapper().Filter("foo");
Assert.IsTrue(results.Any());
```

I got the results of less than 100% code coverage as the OP got. But once I added a second test

```
var results = new MyWrapper().Filter(string.Empty);
Assert.IsTrue(results.Any());
```

I achieved 100%.

My conclusion is that in the above scenario described, one has not provided enough tests to *in code coverage's algorithm's* mind to achieve 100%.

Comment: You may be on to something.  I put together a simple test with a simple object and filtered on only one field.  100% coverage.  As soon as I added an "or" clause (`||`) to the predicate for a second field, the problem returned.  It seems to be something about the chaining of "or" clauses.

Comment: @David Replace the contrived example in your post with the basics of your simple test.

Comment: Added it to the question, including another direction I've taken which seems to get around the problem though I'm not sure it's the best implementation to do it.

Comment: @David thoughts on a bug in code coverage and not your logic. See my update.

Comment: @David Final thoughts added to my post where I reproduced what you saw but also achieved 100%.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll test that when I'm in front of the codebase again.  Currently with an empty string it doesn't even reach the predicate, because no filter is being applied so the method never reaches that.  (A prior `if` condition, also covered by another test.)

Comment: @David I'm still on the fence whether this is a bug or not...it is still running through my head. I may still post the connect issue.